# Variable not getting displayed when printed on another page in PHP

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
session_start();

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Clean up the input values 
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {  
    $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]); 

    $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key])); 
}

$name = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['name'])));
$email = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['email'])));
$subject = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])));
$message = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['message'])));

$successful = "Message was sent";
$failure = "Message was not sent";

$header = "From: $email\r\n";

$validEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if (isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($subject) && isset($message)) {
    if ($validEmail) {
        mail ("myemail@email.com", $subject, $message, $header);
        header("Location: emailsent.php?message=$successful");
    }
    else {
        header("Location: emailnotsent.php?message=$failure");
    }
}
?>
```

emailnotsent.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $failure;
?>
```

emailsent.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $successful;
?>
```

I see the URL with the "Message was sent" but nothing is displayed on the page itself.

Comment: you may want to `urlencode($successful)` and `urlencode($failure)`. Also use `exit();` after your `header();` to stop executing more code. Since those variables will always be SET you may want to check if their `empty()` and valid

Comment: URL-encoding would be a decent idea, but if the strings are provided by the code itself and don't contain characters deemed special in URLs or HTML, they shouldn't cause trouble if not encoded.  At the very least, the redirect should either fail altogether or print the first word ("Message") either way...but most browsers will actually do something alaong the lines of decoding and re-encoding the URL when trying to use it.

Comment: How do i modify the following line: `$header = "From: $email\r\n";` to show the `$name` surrounded by the email? `"Last, First <$email>"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is displayed, because $successful is not defined in emailsent.php. Try to print the GET variable:

```
echo $_GET['message'];
```

See **[Variable Scope.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)**

Comment: How do i modify the following line: `$header = "From: $email\r\n";` to show the `$name` surrounded by the email? `"Last, First <$email>"`

Comment: What if `Last, First` was a variable, in this case `$name`?

Comment: @SiKni8  "$name <$email>"?

Answer (score 1):

emailnotsent.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_GET['message'];
?>
```

emailsent.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_GET['message'];
?>
```

Comment: Actually, he could just use 1 script, instead of 2 for success and fail